# OpenGL ES shader degrades too much performance

Tags: android, iphone, performance, opengl-es, glsl

I'm optimizing a game that works for both, iPhone and Android. I'm using 4 shader to draw the scene and I noticed that if I change one of them to another the fps goes from 32 to 42, even though there's only 1 sprite being drawn with that shader, and the only difference in this 2 shaders is just a product in the fragmente shader.

These are the shaders:

default-2d-tex.shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
precision lowp int;
#endif

#ifdef VERTEX

uniform mat4        umvp;

attribute vec4      avertex;
attribute vec2      auv;

varying vec2        vuv;

void main()
{
    // Pass the texture coordinate attribute to a varying.
    vuv = auv;

    // Here we set the final position to this vertex.
    gl_Position = umvp * avertex;
}

#endif

#ifdef FRAGMENT

uniform sampler2D   map0;
uniform vec4 ucolor;

varying vec2        vuv;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor =  texture2D(map0, vuv) * ucolor;
}

#endif
```

default-2d-tex-white.shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
precision lowp int;
#endif

#ifdef VERTEX

uniform mat4        umvp;

attribute vec4      avertex;
attribute vec2      auv;

varying vec2        vuv;

void main()
{
    // Pass the texture coordinate attribute to a varying.
    vuv = auv;

    // Here we set the final position to this vertex.
    gl_Position = umvp * avertex;
}

#endif

#ifdef FRAGMENT

uniform sampler2D   map0;

varying vec2        vuv;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor =  texture2D(map0, vuv);
}

#endif
```

Again,
If I modify default-2d-tex.shader and remove the product "* ucolor", the fps goes from 32 to 42, and I'm using it for just one sprite in the scene!

Is this normal? Why is this shader being so slow and how can I improve it?

**EDIT:**

I see this performance slowdown on both iPod and Android in an equal ratio. Both are PowerVr SGX GPUs (iPod 3rd gen and Samsung Galaxy SL -PowerVR SGX 530-). iOS version is 4.1 and Android is 2.3.3

The sprite I'm drawing is scaled to fill the screen (scaled to 4x) and I'm drawing it once per frame. It's taken from a texture map so the texture is actually larger (1024x1024) but the portion taken is 80x120. Alpha blending is enabled.

**EDIT 2**

I made a mistake. The sprite is scaled 11x: its 32x48.
If I don't draw that sprite at all, fps goes to 45. I'm drawing a lot of sprites in the scene, why is that one taking so much time? Could it be because it's scaled so much?

Comment: As a suggestion, measure your frame render times, not framerate, when profiling. [Framerate isn't always the best metric](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/23/lying-numbers/). What hardware and OS version were you seeing this slowdown on? Is the slowdown consistent on Android and iOS? How large in pixels is this one sprite? What kind of blending mode do you have enabled?

Comment: I had a hard time finding that the difference in the code is just the final output multiplication in the fragment shader. You should just have posted that part. And I doubt that such a small multiplication is causing the dropdown in performance. How is your render pass setup? If your render setup is simulating more pixels, which is often used for postprocessing this can lead to performance drop.

Comment: Where is the information? You only provide texture size which should be irrelevant. How many pixels does this sprite on the screen occupies? Is it not fullscreen or what do you mean by scaled to 4x?

Comment: @djmj: I clarified that the difference was "* ucolor", and I added all the information. Read it again please, the sprite is scaled to fill the screen (320x480 in ipod, 480x800 in android)

Comment: Note that iOS 4.2 introduced a much better shader compiler, so you might not see as much of a slowdown on devices using that OS version and higher. My guess is that blending is the culprit here, because it's an extremely expensive operation on these devices. Blending can often multiply the impact of additional calculations in a fragment shader. Try rendering your underneath content as opaque elements with blending off first, then enable blending for just this one overlay sprite and draw that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove "* ucolor" from the abovementioned code many things happen:

1. uniform *ucolor* becomes unused
2. GLSL compiler removes this uniform from the active uniforms set
3. when you have you program linked the ID of the missing uniform
   becomes -1
4. when you do glUniform4fv( -1, value ) for the removed uniform it
   just exits instantly, without any update

This is pretty much less work compared to having "* ucolor" in place.

And additionally, this is one less operation per fragment in the fragment shader.

Comment: Then using uniforms at all would be biggest performance killer related to his dropdown in framerate! I never observed such dropdown using uniforms.

Comment: It is. This shader has only 1 uniform that is constantly updated. The uniform was removed. This explains some performance boost. Also the shader itself becomes more lightweight. That explains more speed gain.

Comment: Again: I'm using this shader once per frame. @SergeyK. do you think that shader es that expensive?

Comment: Depends on the number of pixels you draw. If you draw a full-screen quad - it can be that expensive, expecially on the new iPad.

Comment: That's terrible! just one product in the fragment... I'm mostly using the color to change the sprite's alpha, so I may be better using a single float uniform instead of a full color.

Comment: I was waiting for another answer to appear. Anyway, I read somewhere that many mobile gpus have a very limited fill rate, and that it's actually cheaper render hundreds of vertices that look small on the screen than one simple quad as big as the screen.

Comment: @Damian: We've experienced that the fillrate is _very_ limited. A full-screen quad with close-to-trivial shader eats everything up.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your fragment shader in default-2d-tex.shader. You have
uniform vec4 ucolor;
That means, that each of your color's components (RGBA) will be converted to 32-bits float value. And this drops performance heavily.
Should be:
uniform lowp vec4 ucolor;